# Cannot uninstall VirtualBox 5.2.6 from Windows 8.1

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, uninstall

I have upgraded a perfectly running VirtualBox (5.1.x) under Windows 8.1 to the latest 5.2.6, and now I can feel the pain.

The new version fails to launch any virtual machine resulting in the following error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine xxx.
```

So I decided to revert to the previous version to rescue.

But the installer runs untill about 90% of the progress bar, then stays there forever (I mean hours). And even canceling the uninstallation doesn't work.

Can I manually erase what it takes to be able to reinstall the former version ?

Comment: What does "the new version fails to launch any virtual machine" mean? Do you get a specific error message or just blue screen? Did you make sure the Window hypervisor isn't active?

Comment: @0xA3: I get a message "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine xxx". This didn't occur with the previous version and I made no change to my system. But my concern is more how to uninstall.

Comment: The error indicates that this could be a problem with Virtual Box being unable to access the VM files. Either because of missing read/write permissions, or because another (hidden) Virtual Box instance has a lock on the files. The latter also could explain why the uninstall is failing. Check with Task Manager and kill all open Virtual Box processes.

Comment: @0xA3: I didn't mention it, but I already tried that (and also reboots) to no avail.

Comment: And you also checked the permissions on your folder and made sure that the files are not locked by any other application?

Comment: Mh, I am trying to uninstall from the same account that made the installation. But how can I detect a lock ? (Note that I tried uninstalling from the freshly booted system with nothing special being launched...)

Comment: Uninstall VirtualBox and Extension pack completely by using Revo Uninstaller, then reinstall version 5.1. Ensure that Hyper-V is disabled.